# How do I create a new SKBitmap that is black (empty) but opaque?

Tags: xamarin.forms, skiasharp, .net-maui

I am using .net maui and skiasharp, and I'm new to both.
When I create a new SKBitmap and display it, I find it is transparent unless I manually loop through and set the alpha channel to 255. Is there a way to create an image that's fully opaque from the start instead of fully transparent? I want the image to be Bgra8888.

I tried:

```
    SKBitmap dstBitmap = new SKBitmap(width, height);
    SKBitmap dstBitmap = new SKBitmap(width, height, false);
    SKBitmap dstBitmap = new SKBitmap(width, height, true);
    SKBitmap dstBitmap = new SKBitmap(width, height, SKColorType.Bgra8888, SKAlphaType.Opaque);
```

but the 4th byte (alpha) of every pixel is still 0 and I find I need to loop through every pixel and set that byte to 255 in order to see anything before I draw it to a canvas.

```
    byte* dstPtr = (byte*)dstBitmap.GetPixels().ToPointer();
    ...
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
        {
            dstPtr += 3;
            *dstPtr++ = 0xFF;
        }
    }
    ... elsewhere...
    canvas.DrawBitmap(myBitmap, myRect);
```

I can of course just create my own method to create images in this way, which I have, but it seems different from what I've experienced in the past on other platforms, though maybe that's because I typically wouldn't have an alpha channel at all, just RGB888, but that's not an option in skia, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can fill the bitmap with solid color, once you have a `Canvas` for it:

```cs
using Xamarin.Forms;
using SkiaSharp;
// Extension Methods.
using SkiaSharp.Views.Forms;

SKCanvas canvas = new SKCanvas(skbitmap);
// Xamarin.Forms.Color.ToSKColor is in static class "Extensions".
canvas.Clear(Color.Black.ToSKColor());
```

Note: In a draw method, you might instead have a `Surface surface` for the bitmap; the canvas is then `surface.Canvas`.

Comment: I am using image processing functions on the SKBitmap before I ever display it. Only when I'm painting the surface of the SKImageView do I use the canvas and draw the bitmap. Clearing the image at that point would overwrite the image processing work I already did. I guess I can use an SKCanvas in my image processing code. I see a "canvas" more as a view type object that has no business being in my processing code, but maybe that's me crossing wires with a WPF canvas control. If an SKCanvas is really meant to be used within image processing code, ok, I'll mess around with that.

Comment: In Skia, a canvas is not necessarily a "view type object". Its the handle you need to perform any drawing action. That could be to a display surface, but that can also be rendering to a bitmap.